# Accept "Content-Encoding: gzip" in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I'm processing requests in Tornado that comes with `Content-Encoding: gzip` header in the body request. The problem is that Tornado shows a warning:

> [W 150713 17:22:11 httputil:687] Unsupported Content-Encoding: gzip

I'm doing the unzip operation inside the code and it works like a charm but I'd like to get rid of the message.

Is there any way of accepting that `Content-Encoding` in Tornado?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the code you are using? Also, is that the complete line from log?

Comment: Hi @AnandSKumar. Yes, that's the only line in the logs. The next one is the answer code (200).

Answer (score 4):

You must opt-in to handling of gzipped requests by passing `decompress_request=True` to the `HTTPServer` constructor (or `Application.listen`).

Comment: Got same result: `[W 150714 16:59:51 httputil:687] Unsupported Content-Encoding: gzip`. I did a `app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[ (...), (...) ], decompress_request=True)` and it returns the same warning. A simulation of the request can be made by: `curl -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --request POST --data-binary @data.json.gz http://my.url/test -v`

Comment: `decompress_request` is an argument to `HTTPServer`, not `Application`.

Comment: That was it!! Thanks @ben-darnell :-D

Comment: Note: to test this in a `tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase`, you need to make sure that the server used for testing also supports this. It can be done by overriding `get_httpserver_options` in your testcase to `return {"decompress_request": True}`. Not the nicest of solutions, since I now need to make sure that the options here and in my production-server stay in sync, but at least I can test this

Comment: OK, it turns out you can use your own server in testing. See [here](https://gist.github.com/reinhrst/8775b63b1c369773e1f7) for a proof of concept

Comment: Thanks @ben Darnell

Answer (score 0):

Only way u can change function parse_body_arguments in tornado.httputil file. Otherwise remove Content-Encoding in headers arguments

Comment: I would like not to have to change `parse_body_arguments` just for this, since it's working fine. Just wanted to get rid of the warning. Any way of removing the headers inside Tornado before the execution of `parse_body_arguments`? :-\